# Why astype(uint) on np.array doesn't change type of an element of the np.array?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

When converting an np.array to uint8 using **astype** the type of an element of the array doesn't change.

```
>>> x = np.array([[1.0, 2.3], [1.3, 2.9]])
>>> x.astype(uint8)
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2]], dtype=uint8)
 >>> type(x[0,0])
<type 'numpy.float64'>
```

Why the element is still **float64** and not **uint8**?

Comment: As a general rule:  if a method returns something then it doesn't modify the original object. If it doesn't return something then it does modify the original object. This is almost always true with built-in objects, the standard library and most other libraries. In your example it's clear that `astype` is returning something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`astype` returns a copy of the origin array.

Use `x = x.astype(uint8)` instead

Comment: for python3, numpy it should be `x = x.astype(np.uint8) `

Answer (score 1):

**astype** returns a copy of an array, so you must assign it:

```
x = x.astype(uint8)
```